# Matrix-like Idle Animation for Emacs

Tags: emacs

As is, my emacs is set up to show green text on a black background. On seeing it, a friend remarked that I just took it because of the Matrix-like appearance it gives. So, now what I want to do is implement an idle animation for it where, like in the matrix, changing text falls down the screen. Like in the zone out functions, it should run after emacs has been idle for a while. How would this be done?

Comment: Couldn't you just always code while high?  The falling text will come, man.  It will come.

Comment: @belgariontheking That's probably because he'd fall out of the chair ;)

Comment: @samoz: and eventually he'll just sell that chair for weed money.

Comment: @belgariontheking or a red pill... *dun dun dun*

Answer (score 26):

You might want to check out the package zone: <kbd>M-x zone</kbd>

The `'zone-pgm-drip` is like the Matrix drip, only one character at a time.  I'm sure it could be enhanced to be more flood like.  Also, the `'zone-pgm-jitter` has text flooding down, but it's just the text currently on the screen (so it's horizontal extent is limited to what was already showing).  You can just run <kbd>M-x zone</kbd> over and over until you find what you like.

If you want to limit the choices zone uses, you can restrict the array that zone uses:

```
(setq zone-programs [zone-pgm-jitter])
```

The choices for `zone-programs` are:

```
zone-pgm-jitter
zone-pgm-putz-with-case
zone-pgm-dissolve
zone-pgm-explode
zone-pgm-whack-chars
zone-pgm-rotate
zone-pgm-rotate-LR-lockstep
zone-pgm-rotate-RL-lockstep
zone-pgm-rotate-LR-variable
zone-pgm-rotate-RL-variable
zone-pgm-drip
zone-pgm-drip-fretfully
zone-pgm-five-oclock-swan-dive
zone-pgm-martini-swan-dive
zone-pgm-rat-race
zone-pgm-paragraph-spaz
zone-pgm-stress
zone-pgm-stress-destress
zone-pgm-random-life
```

Comment: That is hilarious.. And awesome.  Cant figure out how to specify which zone I want tho, as M-x zone-pgm-jitter doesnt work.  Just M-x zone

Comment: @Silfheed 
(setq zone-programs [zone-pgm-jitter])

Answer (score 3):

You could install zone-matrix from Marmalade. "M-x package-install zone-matrix"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone just made one.  It worked for me after a small amount of tweaking:

https://github.com/emacsmirror/zone-matrix

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the [xmatrix](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/screenshots/) screensaver, which could probably be modified to run in a window other than the X root if you really want it to run it within emacs.  Bonus points if you can modify it to use glyphs based on the text in the current window.  By strange coincidence, [Jamie Zawinski](http://www.jwz.org/) both wrote xmatrix and large chunks of Lucid Emacs, which was subsequently released under an open-source licence as [Xemacs.](http://www.xemacs.org/index.html)

Comment: "strange coincidence" == the scenario described above by @samoz and @belgariontheking.

Comment: That's a bit mean.  I'm sure than when JWZ wrote xmatrix, Lucid Emacs or even Netscape he wasn't taking drugs ... much ;-}